# Bangladeshi came to India as a child, now don’t know what to do

Tags: india

Please kindly answer if anyone can help regarding this matter.

My mom came to India with her 3 children (I am the eldest) 12 years ago, due to unavoidable reasons. At that point the situation was such that she couldn’t think properly and do the correct thing, the only priority was to bring us to India (to my paternal grandparents house, which is originally here).

Due to misinformation and wrong guidance, many mistakes were made, the biggest being not surrendering the passport. Time went by and there was a need to go to Bangladesh to meet her parents.

The only way was to make an Indian passport. Please understand we did not have any correct information and we knew that there was no proper way to get Indian citizenship.

Also my Dads family lives in India. Our dad's actual home is in India but we were born in Bangladesh. We got the Indian passport and travelled to Bangladesh with it.

After a few years it was caught in the airport and the passports of all 4 of us got revoked. Now we are asking for help, but everyone is saying nothing can be done. We can never get citizenship or passport.

Years have passed (12 years), and I wish to go abroad for studies, so do my siblings, but it seems like we will never be able to do anything about this.

PLEASE KINDLY SHARE ANY ADVICE THAT COULD HELP US IN THIS SITUATION.

Comment: When you asked people were that just people or people who studied law and specialized in immigration problems?

Comment: Talk to an immigration lawyer that's familiar with Indian and Bangladeshi rules. This is too complicated for strangers on the Internet. Chances are a lot of the "mistakes" will need to be undone, but only a skilled lawyer looking at all your details can help with that

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @TrainsandPlanes That's an answer. It's the only possible answer.

Comment: P.S. We are bengali Hindus. Our Paternal house is in Kolkata India. But as some of you may be aware, before partition this issue did not exist and some families had houses in both east and west bengal. During 1971 war Bangladeshi Hindus could come to India but unfortunately, due to various financial and familial reasons some people like my father had to stay in bangladesh.

Comment: @TrainsandPlanes Thank you very much for showing a path.Plz can you share in a little bit more detail if possible,how things can work out.We are stateless right now.We dont have any country, but by no means we can go back to Bangladesh, even if that means we never get a passport.But as humans, we also want to live our lives,we havent done any harm to any1 just tried to save ourselves.We knw it was illegal,I hope you understnd,what minorities face nd that surviving becomes the only priority,but making mistakes which I dont know if can be undone ever, will is be possible? plz tell me if you knw.

Comment: This sounds like a case beyond an individual fate, and more like a problem at geopolitical scale. If there are many that are in the same situation, then there's either an established path, or it's up to politicians to create one. I hope someone may be able to provide more information, but this may be beyond a mere Q&A.

Comment: @deceze Yes,millions of people are facing this problem. Bangladesh & Westbengal both have all people speaking bengali,same culture, but two major religions-. Naturally, families were spread across both countries, without a border in between.During partition,30% of the population in Bangladesh(eastpakistan)were Hindus.We are still suffering for what happened 76yearsago. The fortunate ones who happened to be on this side, are not going to help us.

Comment: @barbie31: But what are you trying to do? Remain in India? Remain in Bangladesh? Travel to a third country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in a very difficult situation but here is only ONE thing you should be doing now:

Talk to an immigration lawyer that's familiar with Indian and Bangladeshi rules. This is way too complicated and dangerous for strangers on the Internet. Chances are a lot of the "mistakes" will need to be undone, but only a skilled lawyer looking at all your details can help with that .

DO NOT DO ANYTHING before you have consulted with a lawyer. The worst thing that you can do at the moment is making more "mistakes". Only a lawyer can assess this for your specific situation.

Listening to advise from strangers on the Internet is likely to make it worse.

Comment: I will do so, thank you so much for your reply.